# Django template: {% url 'url_name' %} gives TypeError

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm talking here about Django 1.7.3:

In my urls.py I have this rule: `url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/'}, name='logout_url'),`

In my template I try to get it like so: `{% url 'logout_url' %}`

The computer tells me this: `type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not str` and it highlights the url tag.

What's wrong? :( I tried putting next_page='/' as a parameter in the tag, or removing the kwargs from the url definition, making my own view that calls d.c.a.v.logout, I'm a bit lost.

Full traceback, bit anonymized

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.7.3
Python Version: 2.7.8
Installed Applications:
('admin_tools',
 'admin_tools.theming',
 'admin_tools.dashboard',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'FreqScanner')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Template error:
In template D:\company\OpenShift-App\FreqScanner\templates\FreqScanner\main.html, error at line 45
   type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not str
   35 :                     aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">


   36 :                 <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>


   37 :                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>


   38 :                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>


   39 :                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>


   40 :             </button>


   41 :             <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">App</a>


   42 :         </div>


   43 :         <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">


   44 :             {% if user.is_authenticated %}


   45 :             <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">Welcome, {{ user.username }} | <a href=" {% url 'logout_url' %} " class="navbar-link">Logout</a></p>


   46 :             {% else %}


   47 :                 <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form" method="post" action="{% url 'login_url' %}">


   48 :                     {% csrf_token %}


   49 :                     {% if next %}


   50 :                         <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />


   51 :                     {% endif %}


   52 :                     <div class="form-group">


   53 :                         <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" value="{{username}}" placeholder="Username">


   54 :                     </div>


   55 :                     <div class="form-group">


Traceback:
File "D:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\company\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "D:/company/OpenShift-App\FreqScanner\views.py" in dashboard
  20.     return render(request, 'FreqScanner/dashboard.html', {'results': results, 'last_crawl': last_crawl, 'upload_form': form})
File "D:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\company\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  50.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
File "D:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\company\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  178.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "D:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\company\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  148.             return self._render(context)
File "D:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\company\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  142.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "D:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\company\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "D:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\company\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "D:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\company\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  126.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "D:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\company\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  142.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "D:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\company\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "D:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\company\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "D:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\company\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  312.                 return nodelist.render(context)
File "D:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\company\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  844.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "D:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\company\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  80.             return node.render(context)
File "D:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\company\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  444.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=context.current_app)
File "D:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\company\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  551.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
File "D:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\company\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  415.             self._populate()
File "D:\Python27\VirtualEnvs\company\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  295.                             lookups.appendlist(name, (new_matches, p_pattern + pat, dict(defaults, **pattern.default_kwargs)))

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not str
```

And the full urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from FreqScanner import views


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'Company.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^$', views.dashboard, name='index'),
    url(r'^crawl/$', views.crawl_and_wait, name='crawl'),
    url(r'^alert/$', views.alert_and_wait, name='alert'),
    url(r'^upload/$', views.upload_action, name='upload'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login_user, name='login_url'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/'}, name='logout_url'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls), name='admin_page'),
    url(r'^admin_tools/', include('admin_tools.urls'), 'admin_tools'),
)
```

Comment: Did you try `{% url logout_url %}` ?

Comment: Please can you post the full traceback.

Comment: Hmm. Can you also post the full urls.py?

Comment: I see mistake 1: I forgot name= in the last rule. But admin_page isn't working now.